# How to increase checkbox values ​with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the button is pressed, we clone the email field. Checkbox values ​​conflict. How can I solve this problem? I would be glad if you help. I hope I can.

```js
$('.add-extra-email-button').click(function() {
  $('.clone_edilecek_email').clone(true, true).appendTo('.clone_edilen_email');
  $('.clone_edilen_email .clone_edilecek_email').addClass('single-email remove-email');
  $('.single-email').append('<div class="btn-delete-branch-email"><button class="remove-field-email btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button></div>');
  $('.clone_edilen_email > .single-email').attr("class", "remove-email");
  $('.clone_edilen_email input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(".add-extra-email-button").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(".add-extra-email-button").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    $(".remove-email:last").find('.email-address').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="clone_edilecek_email">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">E-posta</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control email-address" name="email[]" placeholder="E-Posta giriniz">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ban[]" value="1" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="fas fa-ban"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="checkbox" name="circle[]" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-left">
    <button type="button" class="add-extra-email-button btn btn-success" disabled><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="clone_edilen_email"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the index between the brackets of the name. Or use dots: circle[0] or circle.0 most backends get this naming.

Comment: @JoelHarkes Thanks, How do I increase the numbers after cloning?

Comment: with prop function: `$('element').prop('name', 'newName')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set the index between the brackets, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="circle[0]" autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></span>
```

Why? otherwise only the selected checkboxes will be send and the backend. The browser will only send that 2 checkboxes are checked to the backend/server. the server than has no idea which of the checkbox indexes where checked. thats why in the frontend you need to provide an index for each checkbox.

Warning: not all backends understand these kind of form names (but most do).

you could do this like this::

```
var index =1;
$('input').each(function(inputElement) {
  // execute the function for each input element. (might want to do the same for select elements.

  // take the name of that element
  var name = $(inputElement).prop('name');

 // replace [] with the index you want// (warning this only works if you dont use multi dimensional arrays.
  var newName = name.relace('[]','['+index+']');

  // replace the old name with the new name.
  $(inputElement).prop('name',newName);
});
```

note you can use a function like this:

```
function setIndeces(container, index){
  $('input',container).each(function(inputElement){
    var name = $(inputElement).prop('name');
    var newName = name.relace('[]','['+index+']');
    $(inputElement).prop('name',newName);
  });
}

setIndeces($('newAddedDiv', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you insert it into the code I wrote? I tried, but I couldn't.

Comment: @Dodiş you will have to adapt your code yourself and make sure to remember an the index you increase by 1 every time you add a row. Good luck!